# Round the edges of a DropdownButtons's list of items

Tags: flutter

How can I round the edges of a DropdownButton's opened list that holds the DropDownButtonItems?

[image]

This is what I have:

```
String selectedValue;

DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
  child: DropdownButton<String>(
    style: TextStyle(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
      fontSize: 18,
      color: Colors.black,
    ),
    isExpanded: true,
    value: selectedValue, //var that
    items: getDropdownItems4(), //simple function that holds the values of all the items
    onChanged: (String value) {
      setState(() {
        selectedValue = value;
      });
    },
  ),
),
```

Comment: I've never used flutter before but maybe you can use border-radius:50%. Works in css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code of the `DropdownButton` is here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dropdown.dart

When we read it, we discover that most of the code relative to the appearance of the component is private and the style is hardcoded in the file.

For instance, this is where the border radius is defined: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/2f993d70c178f4a927da5d7d76bd527115920695/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dropdown.dart#L49

So, the only option left is to copy/paste that code and edit the style as you wish.

- Copy paste the whole "dropdown.dart" file in "my_dropdown.dart" in your project.
- Change the relative imports in the file (see gist below)
- Import "my_dropdown.dart" where you want to use the component and hide the "official" ones:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'
    hide DropdownButton, DropdownMenuItem, DropdownButtonHideUnderline;
import 'my_dropdown.dart';
```

Example gist: https://gist.github.com/xvrh/29b7ddf5e4dbd47f6382b241c64b8843
[image: dropdown with radius 15]

Be aware that there are lots of downsides with this technic. You are adding 1500 lines of code to your project that won't be maintained/updated/tested by the flutter team anymore.

Comment: You re the true legend. thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

Now the [`DropdownButton`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html) has [`borderRadius`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton/borderRadius.html) property :

```
child: DropdownButton<String>(
              borderRadius:  BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
              items: [...]
            ),
```